# I'm getting strange errors from forge run ios CLI

Tags: trigger.io

After updating to the latest forge tools. I'm getting strange output when I run forge run CLI on OSX. Has anyone seen this, or know how to fix it?

thank you

output from forge run ios:

```
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.68
[   INFO] Running on iOS device: 8f7798207a11e814971472e932bdc5a4741ba81c
[   INFO] Plist OK
[   INFO] 1 Provisioned Device(s):
[   INFO] ['8f7798207a11e814971472e932bdc5a4741ba81c']
[   INFO] Installing app on device 8f7798207a11e814971472e932bdc5a4741ba81c: is it connected?
[   INFO] ------ Install phase ------
[   INFO] [....] Waiting for iOS device to be connected
[   INFO] [  0%] Found device (8f7798207a11e814sdfsdf971472e932bdc5a4741ba81c), beginning install
```

...

```
[   INFO] ------ Debug phase ------
[   INFO] [  0%] Looking up developer disk image
[   INFO] [ 90%] Mounting developer disk image
[   INFO] [ 95%] Developer disk image already mounted
[   INFO] [100%] Connecting to remote debug server
[   INFO] -------------------------
[   INFO] sh: /Applications/TriggerToolkit.app/Contents/MacOS/python: cannot execute binary file
[   INFO] ^D
[   INFO] ^D
[   INFO] ^D
[   INFO] quit
[   INFO] quit
[   INFO] ^D
[   INFO] quit
[   INFO] quit
[   INFO] ^D
[   INFO] quit
[   INFO] ^D
[   INFO] quit
[   INFO] ^D
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like its because that command tries to run python and its attempting to run the wrong python (/Applications/TriggerToolkit.app/Contents/MacOS/python).

This is probably because you've added /Applications/TriggerToolkit.app/Contents/MacOS to the beginning of your PATH, if you move it to the end of your path then the correct python executable should be used.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling (and I assume upgrading) the forge tool kit these errors went away.